# using awk to print backslash

Tags: bash, awk, quoting

I am having trouble printing (or searching) for sequences containing backslashes when using awk
For example -

```
echo "test\test" | awk '{ gsub(/\\\\t/, "\\\\&"); print }'
```

will give the result:

```
test    est
```

because the \t will be interperted as tab. 
I want to be able to have the string as is, meaning:

```
test\test
```

The echo command is just another way for me to check a 1 liner for the awk command to see if it can find a pattern such as \t in a file (using a bash script).
To be more sprcific - If I want to have an awk cmd  that needs to find a sequence of

```
\"
```

I am using the following:

```
awk -v st="$match_string" 'BEGIN {gsub(/\\\\"/,"\\\\&", st)} match($0,st {print;exit}' file.txt
```

but the cmd does not work: for a file with :

```
547 %$ 
236 \"
4523 &* 
8876 (*
8756 "/
...
```

it will output:

```
> \"
8756 "/
```

What is the right way to use awk to find the

```
236 \"
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to perform, but if you want `echo` to print _a literal_ backslash (`\ `), you will need to escape that, as in `echo "test\\test"`.

Comment: Hello tomer. You seem to be using two different accounts here. You might like to [merge them](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Comment: please use double \. .

Answer (score 1):

It's your `echo` that expands the `\t` into a tab character. Don't use `echo` to output strings that contain backslashes. Use `printf` instead.

```
printf '%s\n' 'test\test' | awk '{ print }'
```

See also:

- [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803)

  The take-home message from there is

  > POSIX says: if the first argument is `-n` or any argument contains backslashes, then the behaviour is unspecified.

---

Taking the updated question into account:

You want to match `\"` in the second column of some data, with the string `\"` given as an argument to the `awk` program:

```
string='\\"'
awk -v string="$string" '$2 == string' file
```

This would return

```
236 \"
```

given the data in the question.  Note that you will have to escape the backslash since you need to expand the variable in the shell once when calling `awk`.

You may also use

```
string='\"' awk '$2 == ENVIRON["string"]' file
```

i.e., you pass the string as an environment variable into the `awk` program.  In this case, the backslash does *not* need to be escaped.

To use a regular expression against the whole line, use either

```
string='\\\\"'
awk -v string="$string" '$0 ~ string' file
```

or,

```
string='\\"' awk '$0 ~ ENVIRON["string"]' file
```

Matching a backslash in a regular expression is done with `\\`, so this is what we have to pass to `awk`. Using `awk -v`, each backslash needs to be doubled up due to expanding the value of `$string` on the command line once in the call to `awk`.

Note also that if you had used double quotes to set the value of `string` when using `awk -v` to pass the string into the `awk` program, you would have had to double up all the double quotes *again* (since the shell acts on double quoted backslashes), *and* escape the double quote in the string:

```
string="\\\\\\\\\""
awk -v string="$string" '$0 ~ string' file
```

So, the first line here sets `string` to `\\\\"` in the shell, and the `awk -v string="$string"` will then evaluate to `awk -v string='\\"'` as we needed for matching a backslash and a double quote as a regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

Just `echo "test\\test"` will do what you want , but if you prefer awk ,you can just print it like this :

```
$ echo "test\test" | awk ' { print }'
test\test
```